# Magnitude of effects on Earth's orbit

Tags: gravity

Which has a greater effect on causing the earth to deviate from a perfect elliptical orbit: effects due to gravitational waves or effects due to the earth not being a perfect sphere?

Comment: Possible duplicate  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29827/

Comment: Neither, it's Jupiter and Saturn and the other planets to a lesser extent, depending  on their mass.

Comment: I know there are many effects that are greater than both, but I'm wondering which of the two is greater.

Comment: Gravitational waves from what?